# Avoid uppercase input with jQuery Validation Engine

Tags: regex, regex-negation, jquery-validation-engine

Some users a writing their messages in uppercase only, and I want to avoid that with JQuery Validation Engine.

I have tried many many regex without any success.
Here is the idea for a custom rule to avoid more than 10 uppercase characters:

```
uppercase: {
   regex: /^(![A-Z]{10})+$/,
   alertText: "* uppercase test alert"
},
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to only allow strings with 10 and fewer uppercase letters, you may use

```
/^(?!(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){11})/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qUZPWX/1)

The pattern matches any string that does not contain 11 or more ASCII uppercase letters (so, it may contain 0 to 10 ASCII uppercase letters).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){11})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current position, there are

  - `(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){11}` - 11 occurrences of

    - `[^A-Z]*` - any 0+ chars other than uppercase ASCII letters
    - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter.

If you want to match a string that has no 10 uppercase ASCII letters *on end*:

```
/^(?!.*[A-Z]{11})/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qUZPWX/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string
- `(?!.*[A-Z]{11})` - a negative lookahead that fails the math if there are 11 uppercase ASCII letters after any 0+ chars other than line break chars immediately the right of the current location.